# How do I retain the method attributes of the functions generated through yield in python 2.7?

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have been doing a lot of searching, and I don't think I've really found what I have been looking for.  I will try my best to explain what I am trying to do, and hopefully there is a simple solution, and I'll be glad to have learned something new.

**This is ultimately what I am trying to accomplish:**  Using nosetests, decorate some test cases using the attribute selector plugin, then execute test cases that match a criteria by using the -a switch during commandline invocation.  The attribute values for the tests that are executed are then stored in an external location.  The command line call I'm using is like below:

```
nosetests \testpath\ -a attribute='someValue'
```

I have also created a customized nosetest plugin, which stores the test cases' attributse, and writes them to an external location.  The idea is that I can select a batch of tests, and by storing the attributes of these tests, I can do filtering on these results later for reporting purposes.  I am accessing the method attributes in my plugin by overriding the "wantMethod" method with the code similar to the following:

```
def set_attribs(self, method, attribute):
    if hasattr(method, attribute):
        if not self.method_attributes.has_key(method.__name__):
            self.method_attributes[method.__name__] = {}

        self.method_attributes[method.__name__][attribute] = getattr(method, attribute)

def wantMethod(self, method):
    self.set_attribs(method, "attribute1")
    self.set_attribs(method, "attribute2")
    pass
```

I have this working for pretty much all the tests, except for one case, where the test is uing the "yield" keyword.  What is happening is that the methods that are generated are being executed fine, but then the method attributes are empty for each of the generated functions.

Below is the example of what I am trying to achieve.  The test below retreives a list of values, and for each of those values, yields the results from another function:

```
@attr(attribute1='someValue', attribute2='anotherValue')
def sample_test_generator(self):
    for (key, value) in _input_dictionary.items()
        f = partial(self._do_test, key, value)
        f.attribute1='someValue'
        yield (lambda x: f(), key)

def _do_test(self, input1, input2):
    # Some code
```

From what I have read, and think I understand, when yield is called, it would create a new callable function which then gets executed.  I have been trying to figure out how to retain the attribute values from my sample_test_generator method, but I have not been successful.  I thought I could create a partial method, and then add the attribute to the method, but no luck.  The tests execute without errors at all, it just seems that from my plugin's perspective, the method attributes aren't present, so they don't get recorded.

I realize this a pretty involved question, but I wanted to make sure that the context for what I am trying to achieve is clear.  I have been trying to find information that could help me for this particular case, but I feel like I've reached a stumbling block now, so I would really like to ask the experts for some advice.

Thanks.

** Update **

After reading through the feedback and playing around some more, it looks like if I modified the lambda expression, it would achieve what I am looking for.  In fact, I didn't even need to create the partial function:

```
def sample_test_generator(self):
    for (key, value) in _input_dictionary.items()
        yield (lambda: self._do_test)
```

The only downside to this approach is that the test name will not change.  As I am playing around more, it looks like in nosetests, when a test generator is used, it would actually change the test name in the result based on the keywords it contains.  Same thing was happening when I was using the lambda expression with a parameter.

For example:

1. Using lamdba expression with a parameter: 
       yield (lambda x: self._do_test, "value1")

In nosetests plugin, when you access the test case name, it would be displayed as "sample_test_generator(value1)

1. Using lambda expression without a parameter:
       yield (lambda: self._do_test)

The test case name in this case would be "sample_test_generator".  In my example above, if there are multiple values in the dictionary, then the yield call would occur multiple times.  However, the test name would always remain as "sample_test_generator".  This is not as bad as when I would get the unique test names, but then not be able to store the attribute values at all.  I will keep playing around, but thanks for the feedback so far!

### EDIT

I forgot to come back and provide my final update on how I was able to get this to work in the end, there was a little confusion on my part at first, and after I looked through it some more, I figured out that it had to do with how the tests are recognized:

My original implementation assumed that every test that gets picked up for execution goes through the "wantMethod" call from the plugin's base class.  This is not true when "yield" is used to generate the test, because at this point, the test method has already passed the "wantMethod" call.

However, once the test case is generated through the "yeild" call, it does go through the "startTest" call from the plug-in base class, and this is where I was finally able to store the attribute successfully.

So in a nut shell, my test execution order looked like this:

> nose -> wantMethod(method_name) -> yield -> startTest(yielded_test_name)

In my override of the startTest method, I have the following:

```
def startTest(self, test):
    # If a test is spawned by using the 'yield' keyword, the test names would be the parent test name, appended by the '(' character
    # example:  If the parent test is "smoke_test", the generated test from yield would be "smoke_test('input')
    parent_test_name = test_name.split('(')[0]

    if self.method_attributes.has_key(test_name):
        self._test_attrib = self.method_attributes[test_name]
    elif self.method_attributes.has_key(parent_test_name):
        self._test_attrib = self.method_attributes[parent_test_name]
    else:
        self._test_attrib = None
```

With this implementation, along with my overide of wantMethod, each test spawned by the parent test case also inherits attributes from the parent method, which is what I needed.

Again, thanks to all who send replies.  This was quite a learning experience.

Comment: Can you give an example of what you hope to do with this?  I.e., how is `sample_test_generator` used?

Comment: Hi BrenBarn, sample_test_generator in this case is actually meant to be picked up by nosetest, so that for each item stored in the dictionary, it invokes _do_test with the values, to get different results.

For example, if the input_dictionary contains two items, then _do_test gets invokes twice, each time with different input values.  This because the code does not change, but the input value that we pass in can change over time.

Comment: Why are you yielding a lambda instead of just yielding `f`?  It may be that your problem is you are setting the attribute on `f` but dealing with the lambda instead of `f`.

Comment: Ah, yes I forgot to mention why I used lambda here.  In my first attempt, I actually just yielded f.  However, I got the following error:

ERROR: Failure: TypeError (<functools.partial object at 0x032C7E40> is not a function or method)

Someone mentioned that I should try using lambda instead, so I did that, which at least got me past the error

Comment: Did you try setting the attributes on the lambda instead of on `f`?

Comment: Thanks for the feedback and the tips.  I updated the lambda expression to be just (lambda: f), and that worked for me.  I will update the original post with this info.

Comment: Why are you not using a class for this?

Answer (score 0):

Would this fix your name issue?

```
def _actual_test(x, y):
    assert x == y

def test_yield():
    _actual_test.description = "test_yield_%s_%s" % (5, 5)
    yield _actual_test, 5, 5

    _actual_test.description = "test_yield_%s_%s" % (4, 8)  # fail
    yield _actual_test, 4, 8

    _actual_test.description = "test_yield_%s_%s" % (2, 2)
    yield _actual_test, 2, 2
```

Rename survives `@attr` too.

Comment: btw., I also tried `yield function_with_attrs_already_set`, but my nose somehow ignores attributes in that case, or more accurately, doesn't run attributed tests, whether or not attributes match.

Answer (score 0):

does this work?

```
@attr(attribute1='someValue', attribute2='anotherValue')
def sample_test_generator(self):
    def get_f(f, key):
        return lambda x: f(), key
    for (key, value) in _input_dictionary.items()
        f = partial(self._do_test, key, value)
        f.attribute1='someValue'
        yield get_f(f, key)

def _do_test(self, input1, input2):
    # Some code
```

The Problem ist that the local variables change after you created the lambda.